# Login - pass user data to new windows / store it as static information? [Desktop App]

Tags: c++, oop, user-interface, model-view-controller, authentication

I'm trying to make a desktop C++ application (using Qt, if it matters for this problem) that features an authentication system. It can be used by ONE user at a time. When the application starts, a log in form will allow the user to type his username and password. After logging in, a new window will be displayed. My question is: should I pass the user's ID and/or username to the next window [as a constructor parameter?] (and use such system for other windows as well) OR would it be ok (I'd much rather prefer this) to store this data in the static fields of a class and access it from everywhere? [doesn't sound too bad since I only allow ONE user to be logged in at any time]. I should also mention that I'll be trying to use the Model-View-Controller pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to store it? I mean, once user clicks "Login" on your login dialog, it checks whether entered name/password combination is authorized to use the app and than the rest of the app starts, knowing user is authorized and without any other checks/using of credentials.

In case you do need to store username (for example you display somewhere in header that user is logged in as XXX or you use it for some other reason) I would recommend to save it statically somewhere. The other way (passing it all over the place) means that you would have to store copies userID/name all over the rest of your app.

Also, if you have more user-releated information (like selected theme, some configs, user specific file paths or something) keep it in one place (create struct/object with all this in it)

**Pro tip #1:**

Do not store password in that struct. Once you check whether user is authorized or not dump it. And by that I mean don't just stop using it/forget pointer but overwrite all places in memory where the password was stored to prevent some RAM reading attacks.

```
// Example
char *password = getPasswordFromLoginDialog();

// Do some stuff (check it)

while (*password) { // while we are not at the end of 0 terminated string
    *password = 0; // zero it
    password ++; // move on
}
```

**Pro tip #2:**

Usual way to compare 2 strings is to go char by char and once they are not the same tell that 2 strings differ and thus password is not accepted. However, it takes marginally longer time to find char missmatch at say 7th position than at 1st. Attacker can exploit that using brute-force and statistics and work out password one char by one.

Easy way to defeat this: After user tries to login wait random period of time and after that start checking if the password is correct or not. This way it will disrupt this time based brute-force attack

More proper way how to check whether password is correct or not: Don't check actual password, but hash it first using some crypto-secure hash like SHA256 and then compare hashes. Preferably hash the hash and hash the hash of hash and so on, about 1000 times, so it takes much longer to bruteforce if attacker gets raw hash of password.

**Pro tip #3:**

Never ever hardcode usernames/passwords into your application. It is pretty easy to decompile and pull these pairs from it. I don't know exactly what you are working on, but I would suggest querying 1000 times hashed hashes of password from some SQL database or something like that. If you have to use hardcoded passwords, dont use raw string, but those hashes

**Pro tip #4:**

Use salt ([Salt - wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))). That is pretty much some random data you put before/after password before you hash it. For additional security it is better to assign each user different salt.
Reason for salts is that same passwords have same hashes. When you have lookup table of common passwords and hashes, you can de-hash password very easily. Not using different salt for each user (or not using it at all) has some consequences: when there is a leak of password(hashes) database attacker instantly knows which users have same password

**Pro tip #5:**

If you are using some sort of client-server authorization system, make sure you salt-hash password client side (before sending it over network) and also on server side (before storing to db/comparing against db). This way when there is a leak of db attacker can't use those stored hashes to authorize himself, because they get hashed (once) more on server side before actual authorization process.
Keep in mind, that if attacker intercepts salt-hashed password when client is sending it to server he CAN use it to authorize himself. However, when using network, you should encapsulate all your traffic in some sort of encrypted tunnel (have a look at [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security))

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'm glad to know keeping the info as static isn't a bad idea (and yes, I do need this information further on). Also, thanks for mentioning the struct, I seem to have forgotten about structs :). I was also amazed about the password erase part. I doubt I would've ever thought of something like the possiblity of it being read from RAM.

Comment: Yes, one wouldn't think twice about other processes reading from your RAM. I have been working recently on application which I wanted to be very secure and there are many possible ways attacker can work out a password apart from obvious ones (key logging, ...); I will add some more pro tips to my answer...